# Dev setup for Authorize.NET AcceptJS

Tags: reactjs, authorize.net

I'm trying to setup a dev environment for React version of Authorize.NET AcceptJS.

I have my API server running on localhost:8080 and my react project running on localhost:4200.  Everything works fine up to the point I submit credit card data to the Authorize.NET sandbox.  I get an error "HTTPS connection required."

In the staging environment, on Azure, everything works, so I know the basic logic is right.

I just need to get the setup working in development.  I'm not trying to debug the credit card logic, but I can't get to the logic I'm trying to debug because the card card stuff is failing.  I could put in a bunch of code to bypass the credit card logic when NODE_ENV="development" but I really don't want to do that.  The code is ugly enough as it is.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

With the limited information provided, it sounds like you are trying to access their resources from your dev environment which is not running under https.
You can create a certificate so that you can do your https://localhost rather than http://localhost and that will probably resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, good one.  It turns out all I needed to to was to add a HTTPS=true to my react startup.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be really easy.  I modified my react startup to be...

```
set PORT=4200 && set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start
```

Note that there is no space between the end of "true" and "&&".  This is absolutely critical.

So now I can charge credit cards in the Authorize.NET sandbox.  I do get the annoying Chrome warnings that the certificate I am using is untrusted, but Authorize.NET does not seem to care.  There is a way to get Chrome to trust the localhost certificate but I am happy just ignoring all the warnings.